# Understanding a tail-recursive vector

Tags: scheme, tail-recursion

I have a tail-recursive function which converts a vector into a list. I understand each line individually, but have a couple questions:

Firstly, in the code what does the code `cons ((vector-ref v i) r) (- i 1)` mean? (Marked "Q1".) I know that it takes the `i`'th element of vector `v` and concatenates it  with `i-1`, but why have to be `i-1`? Why not work with `i+1`? e.g. if the vector v length is total 5, then element number 5 is concatenated with the number 4. I understand that it is making the vector list, but why work with `i-1` (reducing)?  Can anyone give me an explanation?

```
(define vector->list:rec
 (lambda (v)
   (letrec ((helper
          (lambda (vec r i)
            (if (< i 0) 
                r
                (helper vec (cons (vector-ref v i) r) (- i 1))  ;; Q1
                ))))
     (if (> (vector-length v) 0)  ;; line 9
      (helper v (cons (vector-ref v (- (vector-length v) 1)) '()) (- (vector-length v) 2))
      '()))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why `i` is decreasing with each call is that `i` is used to determine when we've reached the end of the vector. The idea is that when we call the `helper` function initially, we set `i` to be the length of the vector (minus 2), and then in each recursive call decrease `i` by 1 until it becomes less than 0, at which point we know that we've gone through the whole vector.

The issue causing your confusion, I believe, is that you're parsing the `cons` call incorrectly- counting the parentheses shows us that the call is really `(cons (vector-ref v i) r)` - the `(- i 1)` is just the third argument to `helper`.

Finally, the idea of checking in line 9 that the length of the vector is greater than 0 is that if the vector's length is 0, we just want to return an empty list `'()`; if we didn't do this check, then the call to `(vector-ref v (- (vector-length v) 1))` would become `(vector-ref v -1)` if we input an empty vector, which would obviously fail. I'm not sure what you mean by "total length checking", but `(vector-length v)` does indeed return the entire length of `v`.

Comment: @user1915570 Yes, I was referring to *that* -2 when I wrote that. The reason is that we start off by taking the last element off in `(vector-ref v (- (vector-length v) 1))` -- that's -1 -- and in our check for the end we use `(< i 0)`. If it had been `(<= i 0)` we'd use -1, but since we're checking for a strict less-than it has to be -2 in order for it to be counted correctly. Trace through the code yourself to see what I mean.

Comment: I'd refer you to an [existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion) on tail recursion for your second question.

Comment: Thanks. that I understand now. I added one more question in another answer

Comment: but I don't get why we need to have line 10. Is that because it is not included inside if routine. that's only include the inner loop(?) except the last element (-1) and (-2) => because of we didn't include 0. but here line 10, it is vector element -2 (= the second last element). so it means line 10 concatenate the last element with the second last element. why we need that?

Comment: @user1915570 Line 10 is required to kick off the whole process. The call to `helper` in line 7 allows the program to loop, but in order to start the loop in the first place we need a call to `helper` in line 10.

Comment: it seems I still only understand the definition of tail recursive. when it comes to code, it is still really unclear.. in the previous code if the line 10 : 
(helper vec 
        (- (vector-length vec) 1)
        '())
shouldn't it be like this : (helper vec (cons (vector-ref v i) r) (i)) in Q1?

Comment: @user1915570 Your issue isn't with tail recursion, it's just with recursion in general. You need the call in line 10 just to *call* the recursive function `helper` you've defined above. Remember, that call isn't inside `helper`- `i` and `r` aren't even in scope. Without line 10, you would have defined the function `helper`, but you would never run it.

Answer (score 1):

It's very helpful to use print statements judiciously to understand how a recursive function works. I added

```
      (print r)
```

right below

```
      (lambda (vec r i)
```

I ran the command:

```
(vector->list:rec (vector 1 4 6 8 9 10))
```

Here's the output:

```
(10)
(9 10)
(8 9 10)
(6 8 9 10)
(4 6 8 9 10)
(1 4 6 8 9 10)
=> (1 4 6 8 9 10)
```

When `helper` is called the first time, it is called using a list whose only item is the last item of the vector:

```
      (cons (vector-ref v (- (vector-length v) 1)) '())
```

which could have been made simpler by using

```
      (list (vector-ref v (- (vector-length v) 1)))
```

**Answer to Q1**

The line

```
            (helper vec (cons (vector-ref v i) r) (- i 1))  ;; Q1
```

prepends (in scheme, `cons`es) the `i`-th element of the vector to a list that contains the `i+1`-th and above items of the vector.

In the example that I ran, when `i` is `3`, `r` is `(9 10)`.

If I understand you correctly, this is opposite of what you thought this statement did.

This function recurses from highest valid value of `i` and decrements in every recursive call. That's what you have `(- i 1)` as the last argument of the above call to `helper`.

**Answer to "Also, where is the total length checking?"**

The line

```
 (if (> (vector-length v) 0)  ;; line 9
```

does check whether the total length of the input is greater than 0. Only then it goes through the trouble of calling `helper`. Otherwise, it simply returns an empty list.

Hope that made some sense.

Comment: where can I put (print r) ?

Comment: Right below the line `(lambda (vec r i)`

Comment: when I use print, it shows this ====> print: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier

Comment: I am surprised. The Scheme interpreter you are using doesn't seem to have defined `print`. That's very strange.

Comment: Well, me too. Using Racket anyway. I just started using it. Don't know much about either scheme or Racket